# How do I make a component wait for async data from service

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

A service is fetching api data and I need to keep and use it in many other components every time the url changes (router links) without calling api again. Api should fetch only when the service runs.

I need to make the component method wait until data is available.

(Real code reduced to minimum for readability)

## Service

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData(): void {
    this.http.get(this.endpointUrl).subscribe((res)=>{
      this.data = res
    });
  }

  getData(selectedCategory): DataType {
    return this.data.find(cat => cat === selectedCategory)
  }
```

## Component

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(
      (params: ParamMap) => {
        // I need params before calling service method
        // this method must wait until the "data" is available in service.
        this.selectedCategory = this.service.getData(params.category);
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Without many changes, it would be possible to subscribe to `fetchData()` which instead returns an observable transporting requested data. We use `tap` for the side effect of also setting `this.data` in the Service. Don't forget to `unsubscribe()`! Also mind some syntax errors, I didn't check for them. Suggesting to add typings for `<any>`.

```
  fetchData(): Observable<any>{
   return this.http.get(this.endpointUrl).pipe(
      tap(res => this.data = res),
      catchError(console.log(err))
    )
  }
```

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(
      (params: ParamMap) => {
        this.myService.fetchData().subscribe(res => {
        this.selectedCategory = this.service.getData(params.category);
        // Or use
        // this.selectedCategory = this.res.find(cat => cat === params.category)
         });  
      }
    );
  }
```

### Subscribe in service

Though subscribing in service is not advised (especially `onRoot` Service) because the service will do a request **every time** url changes, but I guess this is what you want. So be warned.

We subscribe to param changes in constructor. Service will request new data on each route change. Queried data will be emitted using `BehaviourSubject` which retains and updates data. Components can subscribe to `BehaviourSubject` instead using `| async` pipe or manual subscription.

Service:

```
let data = new BehaviorSubject(null); 

constructor() {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(
      (params: ParamMap) => {
        this.fetchData().subscribe(res => {
           this.data.next(res);
         });  
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: I had already tried it but as described, I am trying to find a way to not have to call the api everytime url changes. Api should be called only on app load (page refresh) which should keep the value in service which should be accessible by components on routerLink url changes.

Comment: So subscribe to param changes in the service instead and emit requested data. I have added an example for this.

Comment: This subscription will only work on page reload and not with RouterLink url change.

Comment: E.g `router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe()` - I took `activatedRoute` from your example.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the async pipe (if you need to display the data) and
you should avoid nesting subscriptions.

For data persistence over page refresh, you'll need to use the local storage or the session storage. I'm not a big fan of this, but I guess it depends on your requirements.

You can manage your state with the help of a BehaviourSubject, but if you want to do more complicated stuff and to keep your code clean, I'll recommend using a state management library like [@ngrx/component-store](https://ngrx.io/guide/component-store)
.

Your service

```js
private readonly _state = newBehaviourSubject<Record<string, DataType>>(JSON.parse(localStore.getItem('state')) ?? {});
readonly state$ = this._state.asObservable();


getData(category: string) {
        return of(category).pipe(
            withLatestFrom(this.state$), // you don't want to do something like this.state.pipe(...) because you'll resubscribe to it multiple times because the implementation below
            switchMap(([key, data]) => {
                    if (key in data) return of(data[key]); // return the found category

                    return this.http.get(this.endpointUrl).pipe(
                        tap(res => {
                            const updatedData = { ...data, [key]: res };
                            this._state.next(updatedData); // update your state
                            localStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(updatedData) // update local storage
                        })
                    );
                }
            )
    }
```

Component

```js
readonly selectedCategory$ = this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
   map(paramMap => paramMap.get('category')), // I assume that you expect a string
   filter(category => !!category) // it makes sure that the result is not null or undefined
   switchMap(category => this.service.getData(category)),
   catchError(error => {...}), // handle your errors
   filter(res => !!res) // if you want to make sure the response is not null
)
```

Comment: I am sorry for a mistake in my description of requirement. I have edited it to mention that the api will be called on app load (page refresh), but thank you for a solution anyways.

Comment: That's fine. The solution above will work without the local storage anyway. Just remove it from the implementation and give it a try.